# i want to run a query to get Hierarchy of catagory_name

Tags: php, mysql, sql, hierarchy

if my database look like this:-

```
| CATAGORY_ID | CATAGORY_NAME | PARENT_ID |
-------------------------------------------
|           1 |             x |         0 |
|           2 |             y |         1 |
|           3 |             z |         2 |
```

i used this to get one hirarchy but i want ds to run untill its get parent_id =0

```
SELECT catagory_name
FROM catagory_master
WHERE catagory_id = ( 
SELECT parent_id
FROM catagory_master
WHERE catagory_id =4 )
```

if i want x-y-z for catagory_id=3 and x-y for catagory_id=2 and x for catagory_id=1
please help i have to run this in php script

Comment: Use formatting code is impossible to understand

Comment: could you explain further what you really want to do here?

Comment: Short answer: you can't, in a single query. Longer answer here: [Using MySQL query to traverse rows to make a recursive tree](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10646833/using-mysql-query-to-traverse-rows-to-make-a-recursive-tree)

Answer (score 1):

Try this query

```
select 
catagory_id,
catagory_name,
@pv:=parent_id as 'parent_id'
from (select * from table1 order by catagory_id desc)a
join
(select @pv:=3)tmp
where catagory_id=@pv
```

### **[SQL FIDDLE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/e8fc3/15)**:

```
| CATAGORY_ID | CATAGORY_NAME | PARENT_ID |
-------------------------------------------
|           3 |             z |         2 |
|           2 |             y |         1 |
|           1 |             x |         0 |
```

**Note:** This query will work if the `parent_id` is always less than the `category_id` of that record. If you will remove the order by desc field you will get only 1 record. If you want a proper concrete solution than you need a stored proc..

Answer (score 0):

you need to use IN for this if i get what you want!

```
SELECT catagory_name
FROM catagory_master
WHERE catagory_id IN ( 
    SELECT parent_id
    FROM catagory_master
    WHERE catagory_id = 4 )
```

Comment: this will only print x but i want x-y-z

Answer (score 0):

If your database supports RECURSIVE queries, you can do something like this:

```
WITH RECURSIVE category_tree(id, name, path, level) AS (
        SELECT catagory_id, catagory_name, ARRAY[id], 0
    FROM catagory_master
    WHERE parent_id = 0
    UNION ALL
    SELECT catagory_master.catagory_id, catagory_master.catagory_name, path || catagory_master.catagory_id, level + 1
    FROM category_tree
    JOIN catagory_master ON catagory_master.parent_id = category_tree.catagory_id
    WHERE NOT catagory_master.catagory_id = ANY(path)
    )
    SELECT * FROM category_tree where 0 = ANY(path) ORDER BY path ;
```

And you should have something like this, that can be used to buid a tree:

[image]

Comment: MySQL doesn't support recursive queries.