# PSQL: check inheritable user/group-based permissions for a tree structure?

Tags: sql, postgresql, permissions, hierarchical-data

So I have a table which stores `ltree` entries along with [umask](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Umask)-based permissions for them.

```
| entry | user | group | mask |
| a     | 1    | 1     | 644 |
| a.b   | 2    | 1     | 644 |
| a.b.c | 2    | 0     | 600 |
```

Permissions are inheritable, and permission check is currently done client-side, (no caching - whole tree is retrieved to check permissions for given key).

What can be seen as a better workaround?

- Using separate table to keep rights ([this way](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17277941/crud-permissions-for-users-in-a-tree-structure)) - fast to query, slow to update? (10'000 keys, 100' users, 20-30 groups to help organize users => expecting ~200*10000 keys)
- Keep same structure, cache permissions client-side?
- Write a stored procedure to query tree based on provided entry,user,group?
- something else?

Comment: 1) can a user belong to multiple groups 2) can a group belong to a group, or even multiple groups ? 3) if a user or group belongs to multiple groups, which access/mask should be chosen (or should they be ORed together) ?

Comment: @wildplasser 1) yes 2) no 3) one entry has one group, so its access mask will be chosed