# Iterating through items and subitems - knowing when to stop

Tags: php, mysql

I'm building a task system in php/mysql, imagine I have the following structure:

```
id | parentid 
1    0
2    1
3    1
4    1
5    4
```

A parentid of 0 means there are no sub items.

So basically, I need to query all items that have a parentid of 1.

In a tree view example I'd get:

```
1
--2
--3
--4
```

But I also need to grab all the other subitems:

```
1
--2
--3
--4
---5
```

I hope this clears up what I need, this only goes into 3 levels, but I could very well have a huge number of levels.

How should I approach this in MYSQL? Getting a full list of all items with a specific parentid and ALL the other subitems?

Is this even a possible without knowing a limit? Maybe approach this via server side? (but then again, when to stop?)

Comment: I have solved this before by loading the entire table into PHP and then doing my recursive search.

Answer (score 2):

This question has already been answered. Best way to go about this is using recursive query which MySQL doesn't support.

Here is a workaround for it: [Using MySQL query to traverse rows to make a recursive tree](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10646833/using-mysql-query-to-traverse-rows-to-make-a-recursive-tree)

You could do it in PHP or any other language you use for server side but it would take a lot of requests to get all the data you need.