# Selecting chain of tuples in MySQL, Adjacency List?

Tags: mysql, sql, database, hierarchy, adjacency-list

I have a table `transaction`:

```
ID          AMOUNT      PARENT_ID
8135124     1,56        NULL            | ON CHAIN 1
8135125     0,02        8135124         | ON CHAIN 1
8135126     1,09        8135124         | ON CHAIN 1
8135127     0,03        8135126         | ON CHAIN 1
8135128     0,47        8135124         | ON CHAIN 1

8135129     1,00        NULL            | OTHER CHAIN
8135130     0,01        8135129         | OTHER CHAIN
```

I'm trying without success get the complete chain of a given transaction. For example, when give 8135126 the return of the query must be all columns of `transaction` of 8135124, 8135125, 8135126, 8135127 and 8135128 transactions. The same result when give 8135125 or any other link from chain.

Notice that 8135125, 8135126, and 8135128 are children of 8135124 but, 8135127 is child of 8135126.

How to make it in MySQL?

Comment: See the answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10646833/using-mysql-query-to-traverse-rows-to-make-a-recursive-tree

Comment: It's seems to me a Adjacency List. But I not found a way to implements it with MySQL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could not solve with SQL, had to appeal to the language of the application. Was the only solution that met several loops on SQLs.

Answer (score 1):

With 3-4 levels you can use self joins. Unfortunately MySQL doesn't support recursive functions.

Comment: not necessarily have only 3 levels, the depth of the branches can extend far.

Comment: 3-4 levels. BTW. If my answer is helpful please consider to accept it.

Comment: My first attempt was to solve with JOINs and too with UNION, but it did not work. Thanks! But, +1 =)