# How to return 'Father ID' in this query?

Tags: mysql, sqlfiddle

I'm trying to return the father ID of my table (MySQL), this is the return:

```
ID  NOME         PARENT_ID
1   Project      (null)
2   Sub          1
3   Sub-Sub      2
4   Sub-Sub-Sub  3
```

I need this:

```
ID  NOME         PARENT_ID FATHER_ID
1   Project      (null)    (null)
2   Sub          1         1 
3   Sub-Sub      2         1
4   Sub-Sub-Sub  3         1
```

Here is the [fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/993823/1)

Comment: This is basically a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10646833/using-mysql-query-to-traverse-rows-to-make-a-recursive-tree. TLDR: you can't easily do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to use a function like this ([link SO PT-BR](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/43028/como-retornar-o-id-pai-principal-nesta-consulta-mysql)):

```
CREATE FUNCTION getRoot(idSearch INT)
RETURNS INT DETERMINISTIC
BEGIN
  SET @idParent = idSearch;
  WHILE (@idParent != 0) DO
    SET @idFound = @idParent;
    SET @idParent = (SELECT id_parent FROM arvore WHERE id = @idParent);
  END WHILE;
  RETURN @idFound;
END
```

**[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/c2495c/1)**.

**[SQL Fiddle2](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/7620c/1)**.